# How to show a "highlighted area" in Android-Apps

Tags: java, android

Can someone explain me how to show such a highlighted Area ([image])?

I haven't found anything in the web...Suggest me some ideas to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should check this library : [Android Showcase](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView). This should be the thing which you want. : )

Comment: You should accept the answer (press the tick mark) if your question is answered to give credit to the person who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout XML with an ImageView that contains the transparent image you want to show on the screen.
This is the overlay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="YOUR_TRANSPARENT_IMAGE" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="OK" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Modify the main Activity as

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View overlay_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.overlay, null, false);

    Button OK_Button = (Button) overlay_view.findViewById(R.id.button1);


    this.addContentView(overlay_view, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    OK_Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    });

}
```

}

This will create an overlay on the screen which will disaper when clicked on the OK button